# Change an img content from parents hover

Tags: html, css

i have a div which is the container for a button icon. When i hover over the div, i want the button icon to change. I can only make it so when i hover over the icon, it changes.

As the icon is small, it wont change when i hover in the container like i want it to.

Here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qvf90pdd/2/

```
.page-buttons-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}

.main-page-buttons {
    height: 60%;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    min-width: 20px;
}

.main-page-buttons:hover, .page-buttons-container:hover {
    background-color: #559254;
    color: white;
}

#view-page-settings:hover {
    content: url("http://imgur.com/SZ8Cm.jpg");
}

#view-page-settings {
    content: url("https://i.imgur.com/w9g543Q.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this, I've changed your code and now, when you hover over div also the image changes:

```css
.page-buttons-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
  margin:0 ;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color:blue;
}
 .main-page-buttons{
  height: 60%;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  min-width: 20px;
}

 .main-page-buttons:hover, 
 .page-buttons-container:hover{
  background-color: #559254;
  color: white;
 }
 
 .page-buttons-container:hover #view-page-settings {
  content:url("http://imgur.com/SZ8Cm.jpg");
 }
 
 #view-page-settings{
   content:url("https://i.imgur.com/w9g543Q.png");
 }
```

```html
<div id="view-settings-container" class="page-buttons-container">
  <img id="view-page-settings" class="main-page-buttons" alt="Settings"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this rule you're saying that when the container is hovered, apply styles to it:

```
.page-buttons-container:hover {...}
```

But what you really want to say is: when the container is hovered, apply styles to the button inside it:

```
.page-buttons-container:hover .main-page-buttons {...}
```

Comment: like this? - https://jsfiddle.net/qvf90pdd/3/         that didnt change the image

Comment: Now the styles are being applied to your image, but I don't know what you're trying to do, do you want to replace the image on hover?

Comment: You can't set your `<img />` source with css, you should use a normal `div` and `background-image` if you want to switch your images using css.